# How to display items from DB on specific day on different timezones?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Date on remote server is GMT 0. Date on local machine is GMT +3. An item is getting inserted to DB on 00:30 on GMT +3. How to select this item in each timezone properly, so in GMT 0 it will be on x.month and GMT +3 it will be x+1.month?

I have tried this:

```
    let n = new Date();
    const todayStart = new Date(n.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    const todayEnd = new Date(n.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999));

    // mongo query
    date = {
      $gte: desiredDateStart,
      $lte: desiredDateEnd
    };
```

This will be working if the server timezone matches the local's one.
But if there is a gap, for 3 hours for example, the item will be selected only on requested for yesterday.

Comment: Add `1000 * 60 * 60 * hours` to the dates based on the time passed by the client

Comment: Post a full answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the date to the DB using UTC and convert it to the specific timezone when retrieving it.